# How to signal waithandle.waitany when doing async requests?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm using the following sample code to fetch some HTML Pages using async requests.

I don't want to wait until every request is completed that is using WaitHandle.WaitAll, just until the correct value is found.  I'm currently doing it this way, but it feels wrong to send ManualResetEvents to the thread.  Is it how it should be done?  Is there a better way?

```
    public static void runprogram()
    {

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;
        FetchPageDelegate del = new FetchPageDelegate(FetchPage);
        List<HtmlDocument> htmllist = new List<HtmlDocument>();
        List<IAsyncResult> results = new List<IAsyncResult>();
        List<WaitHandle> waitHandles = new List<WaitHandle>();
        List<ManualResetEvent> handles = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            ManualResetEvent e = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            handles.Add(e);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 200; i += 10)
        {
            int y = 0;
            string url = @"URLTOPARSE" + i;
            IAsyncResult result = del.BeginInvoke(url, handles[y], null, null);
            results.Add(result);
            waitHandles.Add(result.AsyncWaitHandle);

            y++;
        }
        //Here i check for a signal
        WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles.ToArray());

        //WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray());

        foreach (IAsyncResult async in results)
        {

           FetchPageDelegate delle = (async as AsyncResult).AsyncDelegate as FetchPageDelegate;
           HtmlDocument htm = delle.EndInvoke(async);

            if(htm.DocumentNode.InnerHtml.Contains("ANYTHING TO CHECK FOR(ONLY A TEST"))
            { 
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use the TPL and the `Task` class instead; it is **much** easier to work with.

Comment: @SLaks Tell me more, got any links?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx